# "Incorrect number of bindings supplied" when inserting into SQLite DB

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to check whether a row exists and contains some expected values, but I keep getting this error:

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1,
> and there are 5 supplied.

Here's a minimal reproduction of the error:

```
import sqlite3

db_file = "test.db"
con = sqlite3.connect(db_file)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS image')
cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE image(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        listing_id TEXT NOT NULL,
        url TEXT NOT NULL,
        image BLOB NOT NULL
    )''')
res = con.execute('''
    SELECT listing_id, url FROM image WHERE listing_id=?
    ''', 'id123')
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 15
      7 cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS image')
      8 cur.execute('''
      9     CREATE TABLE image(
     10         id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   (...)
     13         image BLOB NOT NULL
     14     )''')
---> 15 res = con.execute('''
     16     SELECT listing_id, url FROM image WHERE listing_id=?
     17     ''', 'id123')

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The second argument to `con.execute` expects an iterable, which a string is. So it's unpacking the characters letter-by-letter. Use `con.execute('''SELECT listing_id, url FROM image WHERE listing_id=?''', ('id123',))` to make a tuple of the parameter and stop it unpacking letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you're passing a string `'id123'` when the `execute()` method is expecting a tuple for its parameters. When you provide a string directly, it treats each character in the string as a separate parameter, leading to the incorrect number of bindings error.

Here's how you can fix the error:

```
res = con.execute('''
    SELECT listing_id, url FROM image WHERE listing_id=?
    ''', ('id123',))
```